# What does ++resultLen * sizeof(float)); mean and do?

Tags: c, sizeof

Can you please explain what `++resultLen * sizeof(float)` means?

```
if (mas[i] > mas[i + 1]) 
{
    result = (float*)realloc(result, ++resultLen * sizeof(float));
    result[resultLen - 1] = mas[i];
}
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? `++` or `sizeof`, or something else?

Comment: ++resultLen * sizeof(float)

Comment: Don't cast the result of `realloc`.

Comment: I meant, do you know what `++` operator does? Do you know what `sizeof` operator does? Specify exactly which part you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The operator **sizeof** returns the size of the type passed in parameter on the system you're executing your code. Usually a float would be 4 bytes.

The operator `++` will increment your variable. If it is placed behind the variable, the variable will be incremented after the arithmetic operation in which it participates. Here it is placed before the variable, so it is incremented before the multiplication.

So here you're reallocating memory space for your "result" array, incrementing its size by 1 (float).

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.  `++i` evaluates to `i+i`, and at some point before the next sequence point `i` will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

It means: increase the value of `resultLen` by 1, and then afterwards multiply the new value of `resultLen` with the number of bytes used by a float.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
result = (float*)realloc(result, ++resultLen * sizeof(float));
```

`result` is being `realloc`ed.

```
++resultLen * sizeof(float)
```

is the same as

```
(++resultLen) * sizeof(float)
```

because of [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)(`++` has more precedence than `*`). `resultLen` is first incremented, and then, this value is multiplied with `sizeof(float)`.

---

*Side note*: In C, [don't cast the result of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

++resultLen is equivalent to (resultLen+1)

so the equation becomes 
(resultLen+1)*sizeof(float);

sizeof(float) is normally 4 but OS and architecture dependent, assuming 4.
which gives:
4*resultLen + 4.

HTH